# Send Query String from view to controller using method POST

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am very new at spring MVC. I have been given a requirement that query string should send a data using method POST to controller. I know how it works with GET, but I do not know how to use POST method to attach form values into a query string. I am doing something like this,

```
<form action="/user/userId?firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}" method="POST">
Enter First Name<input type="text" name = "firstname" />
Enter Last Name<input type="text" name = "lastname" />
<input type="submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to attach firstname and lastname to the string. How should I do this?

This is my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/userId",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@RequestParam Map<String,String> queryUser)
{
    System.out.println(queryUser.get("firstName"));
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    Service service = (Service) context.getBean(Service.class);
    /*service.save(queryUser);*/
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SecondPage");
    return model;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Map`? If you know which parameters you want, just declared `@RequestParam` annotated parameters for them directly. You don't need to put them in the URL, these are form parameters.

Comment: Why are you initializing a new `ApplicationContext` on each request?

Comment: I forgot to delete applicationcontext object. 
My question is how to attach the form values i.e. firstname and lastname to query string?@SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: that is requirement given to me and do not know how to attach the form values. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your html code need to be modified,
remove `?firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}` from `action` attribute of `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="/user/userId" method="POST">
Enter First Name<input type="text" name = "firstname" />
Enter Last Name<input type="text" name = "lastname" />
<input type="submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

Now you can use `@RequestParam` to get input values as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/userId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@RequestParam("firstname") String firstname, 
                               @RequestParam("lastname") String lastname)
{
    System.out.println("firstname: "+firstname); // Prints First Name
    System.out.println("lastname: "+lastname); // Prints Last Name
    // Your service call here
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SecondPage");
    return model;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few fundamental problems with your current code:

(1) Using Request Parameters with http POST (not recommended), rather use `@ModelAttribute` as shown below to receive the request data

(2) Loading `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` inside the controller class (this will be done only once during application start up). Rather load the service beans during startup using `component-scan` and `@Autowire` them as shown below

To fix these problems, you can refer the below:

**Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/users")
public class UserController  {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; //Autowire your User Service

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userInput(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
        return "User";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userSubmit(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user, Model model) {

        userService.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("Result", User details added successfully");
        model.addAttribute("userDetails", user);
        return "UserSaveResult";
    }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="/users/save">
Enter First Name<form:input type="text" path = "firstname" />
Enter Last Name<form:input type="text" path = "lastname" />
<input type="submit" value = "Submit" />
</form:form>
```

You can refer [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) for a similar example.